# Getting Error 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (): Using RestTemplate, Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, rest

I have a client-server architecture in REST, Spring MVC. Tghe client is hitting the server URL and sending two parameters along with it. The server is supposed to reply back to the client with a responce value. One the client side I am using RestTemplate to access server URL. When running, the server URL is getting accessed successfully (server side logic is getting executed), but then I am getting the following error on the client side:

```
HTTP Status 400 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

The client side code is:

```
rresult = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/Merchant/api/movieTheater"+params.toString(), ResponseText.class);
```

The esrver side code is:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="movieTheater")
public ResponseText getCustomerInput(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("price") Double price) {
    System.out.println("Requst URL got accessed here");
    ResponseText result = new ResponseText();
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setMovieName(name);
    transaction.setTicketPrice(price);
    transaction.setDatetime(new Date());
    if(transactionService.addTransaction(transaction))
        result.setMessage(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.getStatus());
    else
        result.setMessage(ResponseStatus.FAILED.getStatus());
    return result;
}
```

When I am accessing the URL separately, it is working fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please show the final url generated ?

Comment: Her's is the final URL: http://localhost:8081/Merchant/api/movieTheater?name=Epic&price=300.0

Comment: try remove that `.` in price ..I guess that is causing problem

Comment: I independantly tried the URL both with and without dot. It is working fine. But, from the client side I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!!! I have an inner class for creating the JSON structure in the client side. The solution is to make that class static! As it was not static, it was trying to instantiate, and hence, got the error message: "Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type"

Comment: This saved me, as I was having a similar issue where everything was looking fine but I continue to get an issue.  The result was that I was missing the proper constructor in the request model.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the URL `"http://localhost:8081/Merchant/api/movieTheater"+params.toString()` is incorrect. What's the class name of `params` and what's the result returned by the mothod `toString()`.  `getCustomerInput()` method can't get the arguments value when incorrect URL accessed.

**URL must be like this**

```
http://localhost:8081/Merchant/api/movieTheater?name=xxx&price=1.01
```

Comment: The URL is correct. It is ea=xactly the one you have printed above. My server side method is getting accessed successfully. But, I am not getting anything in return.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace

Comment: I am not getting any exception stack trace. The log is blank. I ran the server side in the debug mode. I am coming successfully to the return statement. But, it seems nothing is happening after that.

Comment: Add log4j.properties to your runtime classpath. Then open the spring log. Logs are very important for us to check the problem

Comment: Sure. Let me do that!

Comment: I am unable to include a log4j file in classpath and using it. Can you please point me to a tutorial for doing this in Eclipse? I searched but couldn't find anything appropriate online.

Comment: I got the logs. Please let me know how I can post it here. It is too long.

Comment: I am getting: Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type